# Alter partition function and partition schema automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

The structure of my tables are below :

```
SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod (ID int, ...)
Document (ID int, SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID Int, ...)
DocumentDetail (ID Int, DocumentID Int, ...)
```

I want to create a partition function and partition schema for partitioning the `Document` table and `DocumentDetail` table, using `SalesCompanyFinancialPeriodID` column value. 
I also want to automatically alter this partition schema and partition function using an  after trigger on `SalesCompanyFinancialPeriod` table.

In other word, I want to automatically create a filegroup in my database when a new `salescompanyfinancialperiod` record  is created, and partition the records of `Document` table and `DocumentDetail` table with a new `salescompanyfinancialperiodid` in this newly created filegroup.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to ask this in dba.stackexchange.com, as it may get more help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://sqlfascination.com/2010/09/12/interval-partitioning-in-sql-server-2008/, which does almost exactly this (Based on 1 table, but it is the same idea.)

He notes that according to MS, the DML trigger cannot do this directly;  quoting Books OnLine: "...the following Transact-SQL statements are not allowed inside the body of a DML trigger when it is used against the table or view that is the target of the triggering action ..., ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION, ..."

He says it is untrue, but I would be careful. You could, instead, create a stored procedure that altered the partitions that is run based on a trigger. This is somewhat more safe, as the statement would need to run as the database owner and have dataspace permissions, which might be scary to have in a trigger directly.

Side note - In SQL 2008, there is no list partition, only range partitions, so this would be annoying even manually. You can trick it, per the following: 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/partition/64740/